# Why I could not change this eagle NFC class6 antenna footprint?

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-antenna, nfc

I am designing a NFC board prototype that uses NT3H1101 chip. For this, I use NXP AN11276 antenna design guide. This document contains sample file download links for class 6 antennas.

I downloaded this file. I can associate this footpirint to a symbol and use it in eagle. There's no problem with that. I want to change the widths or lengths of roads of this ready antenna design. But the design is like a mold. I can't change anything. As if it was locked. Anyone have any idea about this topic?

NT3H1101 datasheet: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/30/NT3H1101_1201-1127167.pdf

AN11706 design guide: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN11706.pdf

(The links in pdf are dead. I found the file here.)
https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag/nfc-tags-for-electronics/ntag-ic-iplus-i-nfc-forum-type-2-tag-with-ic-interface:NTAG_I2C?&fpsp=1&tab=Documentation_Tab#nogo

(Also I uploaded it for you. This includes all the files mentioned in pdf.) 
https://www.dosya.tc/server25/b4mb6d/AN11276_1_.zip.html

[image: this is antenna]

Comment: Eagle isn't a parametric design software like Fusion or Solidworks, you can't just change one parameter and expect all the others that it affects (like the trace spacing) to change with it. You should be able to open the library and edit the footprint if you want, but you are going to have some issues if you want to increase the width of the traces or the length, you'd almost be better off starting from scratch.

Comment: I would look for a script that can generate these patch antenna's, something that you can input the trace width, total length, width, etc. and then it generates the footprint for you. I'm not sure it exists though.

Comment: It's not a patch antenna; it's a coil of wire.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, wrong type I used, don't think that changes anything though.

Comment: I think I couldn't explain my problem well. If you have time, would you please download the file I mentioned and open the brd file in the folder named class6 and try to edit it?

Answer (score 1):

This antenna is placed in the brd file as library element. You can change everything but must open the library first. Open .brd file and run ULP 'exp-lbrs'. This will export library from brd file and then you can open package L_PICC_CLASS6_50PF_01 inside this library.